# check two input element's names are different or not using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array in which the values of check boxes gets stored on user click. Now I need to use an if loop for a particular logic in my code to give a condition whether the elements inside the array have same name (group check box name) or different names. How can I do it in javascript or jquery?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: this website is a gold mine, just have a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 0):

```
var Array = ['bob','bob','smith','smith','john','john'];
var UniqueArray = new Array();

var obj = {};

$.each(Array , function(i,value) {
  if(!obj[value]) {
    obj[value] = true;
    UniqueArray.push(value)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like this.

```js
$(function() {

  // create an array.
  var elements = [];

  // click event for all input of type checkbox.
  $('[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function() {

    // restrict no. of items to be inserted into the array to 2
    if (elements.length <= 2) {

      // push each element to array.
      elements.push($(this));
    }

    // compare name attribute of 1st and 2nd element in array.
    if (elements.length == 2) {
      if (elements[0].attr('name') == elements[1].attr('name')) {
        alert('elements with same name');
      } else {
        alert('elements with differnt name');
      }

      //clear all elements from array.
      elements = [];
      //clear all checkbox.
      $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    }

    // if you want to iterate through array use $.each
    /*$.each(elements,function(index,data){
      alert(data.attr('name'));
    });
    */

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
first checkbox - :"myCheckBox":
<input type="checkbox" name=myCheckBox id="cbxCustom1" />
<br>second checkbox - :"myCheckBox":
<input type="checkbox" name=myCheckBox id="cbxCustom2" />
<br>third checkbox - :"myCheckBoxNew":
<input type="checkbox" name=myCheckBoxNew id="cbxCustom3" />
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it. But its giving me an error filter[0].attr is not a function. Here filter is my array.

Comment: @ShenbagaRajan No, this snippet is not giving any error for me, its working fine for me. when its firing error ?. if you have your code please attach it with your question.

Comment: while (i<filter.length) {
    
    if(filter.length==1){
    X+= ''+ filter[i] +''
    console.log(X);
}
    else if(filter.length>1){
         
      if (filter[0].attr('name') == filter[1].attr('name')) {
        X+=''+'and'+''+ filter[i]+'' 
      } else {
        X+=''+'or'+''+ filter[i]+'' 
      }

    
    console.log(X);
}
    i++  
    console.log(X);  

    }                                                                                                      In the 7th line its giving me an error

Comment: Not able to properly aligh it

Comment: @ShenbagaRajan Please post your full script in your question itself. or give me a link to fiddler